# Best way to create dynamic Swift framework for Objective-c Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

We've planned to create a dynamic framework using Swift code, this framework has to act as independent for Objective C and Swift project.

1. Please suggest what are the best way to give input/callback to framework from project.
2. How we can make more configurable based on application
3. what are design pattern we can use to construct framework

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I'd start with reading Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Writing Swift Classes and Protocols with Objective-C Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-ID86).